# Running a command line through shell script is not working

Tags: shell

I have an application in Unix. I use the below command to connect to it:
./application -a "connect"

I want to do the same through the shell script, for which i assigned the command line to a variable like:

```
newcommand = './application -a "connect"'
$newcommand
```

But this is not working.

However the first part of the code is working. i.e.,:

```
newcommand = "./application"

$newcommand
```

Can anyone point out what i am missing.

Comment: What does your script look like and what error message are you getting?

Comment: Yeah.  @Geouse Feroz, it would be handy to know exactly what you run, exactly what happens and exactly what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, this:

```
newcommand = "./application"
```

...has the shell run the command, `newcommand` with the arguments, `=`, and `./application`.

In shell simple assignments cannot have any unprotected whitespace or they'll be interpreted as a command.

Consider:

```
newcommand=./application
$newcommand
```

...notice that there's no space around the `=` sign in the assignment.